# Compare results of two recording controllers in jmeter and reflect the result on a sheet

Tags: jmeter

I have a thread group and in that thread group we have two recording controllers, and we have an **HTTP(s) test script recorder** for the test plan so that we can record the test cases through browsers.

So **for recording controller 1** - We have recorded test cases from an URL which is connected to different server and database say `https://qa.testig.com/dev111` and we will record the test cases.

**for recording controller 2** - We also have recorded test cases from an URL which is connected to different server and database say `https://qa.testig.com/dev222` and we will record the test cases.

**We have performed the same test steps as for both the URL's**

We want to compare the results of both the controllers and reflect them over a sheet.

Please tell me if further information is required.

Answer (score 0):

You may add [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to each of [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#script-recorder).
All recorded samples will be shown in this listener view. Also you can specify file name and configure format (XML or CSV) and data to save recorded requests to files, so you will ba able to campare two recorded files.
Choose View Results Tree and click Configure to set sample result save configuration:

[image]

Also you can use [Recording Template](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-recording/) to create project with Tree View Result added to recorder.

Here is a [online diff checker](https://www.diffchecker.com) you may use, for example.

Comment: This is not differentiating the results for the URL's also i cannot identify what is the response time for the same HTTP request for both the URL's